# "Unable to view metadata for files"

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I have met an issue of google cloud dataflow. The same job I setup yesterday, was executed successfully. But I can't do it this morning. The error message shows that

### "Unable to view metadata for files: gs://ntu-project-data/data_src/hepth-converge-m".

It failed at the last step of pipeline, which is writing output file to the bucket.

### "final result/WriteImpl/write_bundles failed.

I don't know if it the bug is in my code, or if should I change the directory structure of my data source. Here's my directory structure as below. The binary and tmp directory are specified by the argument --staging_location & --temp_location respectively.

```
> bucket
>> data source 
>>>binary&tmp
```

Comment: This sounds like a permissions problem with GCS, although it could be something else too.  If you provide a job ID, I can provide more detailed information about what exactly went wrong.

Comment: thx a lot. In the end I found that it is a stupid problem, and fix it. But now face another little issue. the document shows we can specify the worker in which area but I can't change from default us-central to asia-east by adding agrument --zoom asiz-east is there any problem of my arguments

Comment: The flag to pass is --zone.  You need to pass the full zone name, not just the region, such as asia-east1-a

Comment: Could you add an answer corresponding to the solution, please?